# Nodemon failed to start process because node exec was not found

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nodemon

New to this DevOps thing. So I'm trying to docker-compose my nodejs express app but I keep running into this error
[image]

I'm not sure what that is or how to get rid of I've read some other posts that said run

> npm install node --save-dev; tried that removed the images & container rebuilt and I'm still getting this error :(

Does anyone know why this is happenning? I'll post some files below maybe I missed something :/

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3081

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    web:
        build: ./
        command: nodemon -L app.js
        ports:
            - "3081:3081"
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/app
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "docker-web-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -L app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^3.2.4",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.6",
    "node": "^18.5.0",
    "npm": "^8.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker volume is removing your node models.
Please add new entry as below  to prevent.

```
 volumes:
    - ./:/usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Or  else use name volume

```
     volumes:
        - volume_name:/usr/src/app
```

Comment: I'd suggest removing the `volumes:` block entirely – the code is already built into the image and you don't need to also mount it from the host.  Mounting a named volume over the code doesn't really make sense; its only visible effect will be causing changes in the code to be hidden even if you rebuild the image (the named volume contents take precedence).